# Firefox doesn't show background image

Tags: javascript, image, background, preload

I build a site for a fotographer where you can flip trough his photo's. The photo's are the body background images. I preload them using the folowing script

```
  function preloadImage(source, destElem) {

        var image = new Image();

        image.src = source;

        image.onload = function () {
          setTimeout(function(){
            var cssBackground = 'url(' + image.src + ')';
            $(destElem).css('background-image', cssBackground);
          }, 100);

        };

  }
```

Now this works fine in Safari,Chrome but in firfox when this function is fired the background turns white and the picture doesnt show up until the cursor moves over a image.

First I thougt that the background image was set before it was finished loading. Thats why i tried the imange.onload function but it doesn't seem to work.

If somebody knows what going wrong it would by greatly appreciated.

Comment: "`cursor moves over a image`" Which image? The one which is not shown?

Comment: Their are a few images on the page. The image's have a onclick function that trigger the preload and changes teh background.

Comment: Works at my end. Can you share your page or reproduce the same in a jsfiddle?

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the code calling `preloadImage()`. Can you provide more code, and maybe save a minimal example on http://jsfiddle.net ? This way we can reproduce your issue (or most likely you'll find the trouble source while creating a fiddle).

Comment: I can give you the site. www.martijnvandegriendt.nl

Comment: Any ideas i am realy stuck with this?